# In Android Studio, retrieving Data from Firebase does not work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When running the app the data is not retrieved but when debugging i can see where it is in terms of the database link.

When it runs and get to addValueEventListener, it doesn't go into the function which is pretty weird, don't know if this is because its async or not but either way data from Firebase does not get retrieved.

```
public GarbageItems(int itemNum) {
    String itemId = String.valueOf(itemNum);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    gameObjectRef = database.getReference().child("gameObjects");

    itemInformationGrabber(gameObjectRef, itemId);

  }//GarbageItems(Constructor)


private void itemInformationGrabber(DatabaseReference gameObjectRef, String itemId) {
    DatabaseReference dataReference = gameObjectRef.child(itemId);

    DatabaseReference itemColor = dataReference.child("Color");
    itemColor.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String color = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        setColor(color);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
    });
  }
```

This is in a different classs that calls GarbageItem

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    colorTextView = findViewById(R.id.ColorTextView);
    itemTextView = findViewById(R.id.ItemNameTextView);

    GarbageItems garbageItems = new GarbageItems(1);
    Color =  garbageItems.getColor();

  }
```

[image]

Comment: Realtime Database queries are, in fact, asynchronous. Set your breakpoint inside the callback.

Comment: Thanks for this, so since this function is a class I'm trying to send the data between the classes, don't know if this is because its async, but the data that's sent is always null not sure how to fix.

Comment: I don't see where or how you're trying to send data that results from the query, so it's impossible to say from what you're showing now.  In fact, your code doesn't do anything at all with the query results except pull a string out of a snapshot.

Comment: Hey Doug I appreciate the Help, so under the edited section in my question there should be the code that clears up what Im trying to do. also made an edit as to what I do in onDataChange.

Comment: The problem is that because its async i cant store it in a global variable. wondering if there are better ways to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
private void itemInformationGrabber(DatabaseReference gameObjectRef, String itemId) {
DatabaseReference dataReference = gameObjectRef.child(itemId);

DatabaseReference itemColor = dataReference.child("Color");
itemColor.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(Datasnapshot dataSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

    String color = dataSnap.child("Color").getValue(String.class);

    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

  }
});
```

}

Hope it helps you :)